# Set input value on page load with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, activex

I want to update the value of an hidden field using javascript, I don't understand why my code doesn't work.

```
<form id="install" action="" method="post">
<input id="idposte" type="hidden" value="">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var wshnetwork=new ActiveXObject("wscript.network");
var identifiant=wshnetwork.computername;
document.getElementById('idposte').value=identifiant;
</script>
```

I think `document.getElementById('idposte').value=identifiant;`is not executed. I'm using IE8, this code is for an Intranet website (this is why I need the computer name).

Thank you very much.

Comment: Using straight javascript and jquery i can answer but im not sure about activeX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function does not work, that's caused by disabled `ActiveX` controls.

If you're not receiving the data at the server's side, that's because you haven't attached a `name` attribute to your `<input>` element.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the ActiveX is working, I can display the computer name using alert();

Comment: @KevinPFEFER Then the problem is caused by the second point. This should print the same message: `alert(document.getElementById('idposte').value);`.

Comment: You're right Rob, I didn't realize that IE does not update the source code page when I'm using javascript... It seems that my code is working...

Comment: @KevinPFEFER Add `name="variable"` to your `<input>` element if you want to submit the data in a form.